# Trying to fit the size of my table into my aside section

Tags: html

So I am trying to fit my table in my aside section. I have tried to make the width="100", "50", etc but it doesn't make any difference.Here is my code:

```
<table width="100%">
           <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
           </tr>
             <th>Online @ 6:00pm-8:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 3:00pm-5:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 3:00pm-5:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 3:00pm-5:00pm</th>
             <th><strong>BYE BYE</strong></th>
             <th>Online @ 6:00pm-8:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 6:00pm-8:00pm</th>
             <th></th>
           <tr>
           </tr>

             </table>
```

Comment: can you make jsfiddle of full code?

Answer (score 0):

```
      <html>
           <section>
              <p>
              Please make your order here by filling out your information and a brief description
              of what your looking for. I will contact you back as soon as I can.  
              </p>

              <form id="order" name="order"
                   method="post">


                 <fieldset id="custInfo">
                 <legend>Customer Information</legend>

                 <label for="custname">Name *</label>
                 <input name="custname" id="custname" 
                       placeholder="first and last name" 
                       required= "required" />

                 <label for="street">Street address</label>
                 <input name="street" id="street" />
                   <br>
                 <label for="city">City</label>
                 <input name="city" id="city" placeholder="Ormund Beach"/>

                 <label for="state">State(abbr.)</label>
                 <input name="state" id="state" placeholder="FL"/>
                    <br>
                 <label for="zip">Postal code</label>
                  <input name="zip" id="zip" 
                        placeholder="nnnnn (-nnnnn)" 
                        pattern="^\d{5}(\-\d{4})?$ />

                 <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
                 <input name="phone" id="phone"type="tel" 
                       placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn"
                       pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" />
                     <br>
                 <label for="email">E-mail *</label>
                 <input name="email" id="email" type="email"required= "required" />
                     <br>           
                  <label for="sets">Would you like any of our sets</label>
                  <input name="sets" id="favDish" list="itemsets" />






                 </fieldset>

                    <fieldset id="order">
                    <legend>Order your Items</legend>

                    <label for="visitdate">Date of visit</label>
                    <input name="visitdate" id="visitdate" type="date"/>

                     <label>Order type</label>
                     <select name="ordertype" id="ordertype">
                     <option value="type1">Necklace Set</option>
                     <option value="type2">Beachwear</option>
                     <option value="type3" selected="selected">Ring Set</option>
                     <option value="type4">None</option>
                     </select>

                     <br>




                     <label>Did your find everything easy?</label>
                         <fieldset class="optionGroup">
                         <label for="sYes">Yes</label>
                         <input type="radio" name="serviceFriendly" id="sYes"
                                    value="yes" />

                         <label for="sNo">No</label>
                         <input type="radio" name="serviceFriendly" id="sNo"
                                    value="no" />



                          </fieldset>


                               <label>Was it easy to browse through everything?</label>

                               <fieldset class="optionGroup">
                               <label for="oYesYes">Yes</label>
                               <input type="radio" name="orderCorrect" id="oYes"
                                           value="yes" />


                               <label for="oNo">No</label>
                               <input type="radio" name="orderCorrect" id="oNo"
                                            value="no"/>
                               </fieldset>

                                     <label for="comment ">Tell us more about your experience!</label>
                                     <textarea name="comments" id="comments"></textarea>



                    </fieldset> 


     <label id="newsletter">
          <input type="checkbox" name="newscb" />
           Give me your E-mail to receive specials and more information!
     </label>

     <p>
          <input type="submit" value="Submit Your Order" />
          <input type="reset" value="Cancel" />
     </p>


      </form>



          </section>

            <aside>

             <table class="schedule">
           <tr>
            <th>Monday</th>
            <th>Tuesday</th>
            <th>Wednesday</th>
            <th>Thursday</th>
            <th>Friday</th>
            <th>Saturday</th>
            <th>Sunday</th>
           </tr>
             <th>Online @ 6:00pm-8:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 3:00pm-5:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 3:00pm-5:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 3:00pm-5:00pm</th>
             <th><strong>BYE BYE</strong></th>
             <th>Online @ 6:00pm-8:00pm</th>
             <th>Online @ 6:00pm-8:00pm</th>
             <th></th>
           <tr>
           </tr>

             </table>

            </aside>

                 <footer>
                      <address>
                      Leilani's Accessories
                      1234 Abby go drive
                      Tampa, FL 33618
                      </address>
                 </footer>



</body>
```